# PDF Export of logarithmic histogram contains no axes labeling

Tags: plotting, histograms

I have the following data:

```
data = {25,25,20,17,5,36,4,7,11,4,16,4,4,8,10,6,6,14,7,10,5,6,4,14,9,17,5,10,8,16,4,4,4,4,16,7,17,14,25,9,5,16,10,11,7,21,19,10,8,4,11,7,10,4,16,8,6,11,8,6,4,8,19,4,9,10,8,8,5,18,5,5,11,4,10,5,6,16,10,5,5,11,13,15,5,9,7,17,5,14,4,6,4,12,6,5,4,5,5,4,5,9,9,5,7,7,10,10,4,10,5,8,6,4,6,5,11,4,11,12,5,4,5,4,8,6,16,19,5,7,5,10,4,4,7,6,11,5,19,6,5,11,5,18,9,4,4,6,5,9,12,4,8,13,12,6,5,4,13,5,10,6,7,7,5,7,25,6,4,21,9,4,5,20,4,10,5,4,7,5,18,17,12,10,6,8,19,7,6,6,18,5,8,4,12,10,5,4,6,11,13,8,4,6,5,5,5,9,10,4,4,12,9,7,9,9,6,4,19,6,8,5,12,12,6,14,9,10,17,16,7,4,5,5,13,4,5,6,8,4,6,11,6,7,5,4,4,8,10,19,5,4,10,5,5,4,5,15,9,14,17,6,7,9,4,15,9,7,18,4,9,9,4,6,11,5,7,10,4,11,9,8,14,8,10,8,8,4,5,15,5,5,5,9,9,7,13,6,8,7,5,4,6,4,6,4,4,4,8,8,5,4,4,4,4,9,7,5,7,9,5,4,4,19,6,5,9,4,8,4,4,4,8,8,6,12,16,16,17,5,5,7,6,4,16,7,5,6,15,4,8,22,20,9,13,5,6,5,5,5,12,4,12,19,5,7,9,9,6,5,6,4,8,11,8,5,4,7,8,9,8,9,6,4,6,10,8,11,7,8,9,4,5,4,5,7,7,7,6,4,4,5,12,5,7,10,9,5,10,5,4,4,5,6,4,9,5,5,6,4,6,9,5,18,12,5,10,21,16,12,7,6,9,9,10,7,7,7,12,4,5,6,13,5,6,8,7,6,10,7,9,14,4,10,6,4,5,6,9,7,4,7,9,8,5,6,6,16,6,6,8,6,4,5,6,10,20,7,5,4,10,6,8,8,12,5,10,9,18,21,5,6,5,5,14,7,14,9,5,18,9,10,17,6,4,8,4,14,7,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,8,9,10,10,7,9,4,4,12,4,4,4,11,5,8,7,4,4,21,5,7,4,7,9,4,17,6,9,6,4,4,5,4,4,13,6,5,5,4,5,5,11,11,5,8,4,5,5,18,6,8,10,11,8,7,8,8,5,5,9,5,6,4,7,4,6,5,5,9,9,5,15,7,4,7,6,8,6,9,5,5,10,9,5,11,11,5,4,11,4,6,6,5,4,5,7,5,7,14,4,4,4,4,7,8,8,7,7,5,5,12,5,8,8,10,16,5,4,5,10,12,9,7,7,4,22,4,8,12,11,5,17,7,12,10,5,7,6,10,10,4,6,6,6,4,4,9,5,6,6,5,9,10,5,6,7,5,12,4,4,4,21,8,4,6,5,5,5,6,11,12,6,13,7,4,13,8,4,9,10,5,5,8,5,5,5,9,12,6,5,8,4,10,11,13,11,16,10,5,7,7,4,4,12,5,10,5,17,9,6,6,5,6,7,7,7,9,11,8,7,8,5,5,7,5,7,11,4,8,10,6,4,4,10,10,11,5,6,8,6,8,12,9,14,10,5,13,7,10,8,7,4,6,4,20,6,8,4,11,7,5,4,5,7,5,12,9,12,7,4,5,4,5,5,10,16,11,6,5,14,10,6,4,5,4,6,6,4,7,6,5,4,5,5,10,6,6,4,4,5,9,10,5,4,9,8,4,11,8,5,9,8,5,4,8,4,11,8,9,7,8,10,4,9,13,8,5,5,7,10,5,6,16,5,4,4,7,6,4,18,11,8,4,8,9,6,9,6,10,17,14,9,5,5,9,6,10,8,4,5,10,6,6,8,9,5,8,4,6,8,10,4,6,4,5,14,8,4,9,4,4,9,8,14,4,5,6,10,6,19,4,5,4,4,9,13,7,5,7,9,5,7,7,8,5,7,5,5,9,14,10,23,6,4,4,5,4,6,14,11,8,11,10,9,5,8,7,6,13,8,8,7,6,4,12,5,8,10,5,5,4,5,8,5,4,5,9,8,7,8,5,5,9,6,6,4,5,5,5,4,5,8,7,7,11,14,6,18,6,6,5,5,6,5,12,9,6,9,7,21,7,4,7,6,9,8,7,4,5,7,10,6,9,4,5,4,9,6,11,5,8,6,8,8,6,8,5,7,6,9,6,6,5,13,4,4,4,4,7,4,4,5,5,6,13,5,5,7,4,6,6,6,5,13,12,5,5,12,7,10,17,20,15,9,5,5,6,8,15,6,4,4,4,5,7,4,6,5,5,4,11,4,7,4,10,10,21,8,6,9,5,4,5,4,6,6,4,7,6,4,5,4,12,12,5,8,6,12,10,7,6,5,5,4,4,11,10,6,5,6,8,10,11,18,19,5,7,4,10,6,4,7,12,7,19,5,4,6,5,9,5,5,7,22,5,10,12,7,8,8,8,5,11,13,16,5,9,5,4,4,8,6,7,5,4,7,8,7,4,5,6,11,5,5,5,4,6,12,7,12,4,4,5,5,5,5,13,4,5,7,6,5,8,10,5,10,5,5,10,6,5,6,8,6,5,5,5,9,6,17,4,6,5,4,18,18,4,8,28,5,5,11,12,7,8,5,12,6,5,7,9,10,6,10,5,5,5,4,7,7,6,6,5,4,8,4,5,10,6,8,10,9,9,7,6,6,5,5,5,5,5,9,7,15,5,5,6,4,11,13,5,5,13,8,4,4,7,8,20,6,10,4,5,4,5,8,6,5,7,5,9,7,5,8,4,5,5,10,5,11,10,5,4,5,13,8,6,7,6,6,5,8,9,8,7,7,6,5,12,6,5,5,6,10,5,5,9,8,5,6,4,7,4,9,16,4,5,4,4,7,16,4,5,4,12,11,6,5,4,5,10,4,6,7,5,5,8,6,5,4,6,6,7,4,5,5,6,6,5,17,4,5,8,11,6,22,5,6,6,14,4,5,6,9,4,4,9,11,7,6,6,6,8,4,5,4,7,6,5,4,9,5,5,6,6,9,4,10,7,5,5,11,9,12,8,5,5,5,6,4,6,6,5,8,6,6,5,6,6,5,10,4,6,6,4,4,7,4,5,8,7,10,4,5,5,6,8,7,20,4,4,4,7,7,8,5,10,6,8,10,7,5,5,9,4,4,6,10,10,8,4,12,4,10,11,14,4,8,10,9,8,5,6,4,15,6,7,5,5,5,7,6,4,7,4,9,12,4,4,9,15,6,4,8,10,4,4,6,4,7,19,8,8,8,4,4,6,11,4,5,5,9,29,6,4,7,8,6,26,6,5,4,10,5,12,7,7,6,11,6,5,4,4,6,11,4,5,4,5,6,9,5,5,8,9,7,15,9,6,7,14,15,10,6,6,9,5,9,10,6,14,5,5,4,21,20,4,4,4,11,20,4,6,9,8,5,5,5,8,4,11,11,10,4,8,12,7,4,9,4,5,7,9,4,6,4,4,4,5,4,11,6,6,4,4,5,7,10,5,5,10,5,4,5,4,12,5,19,5,9,11,10,13,11,7,7,14,5,12,7,7,7,9,13,10,5,4,8,4,9,5,10,5,7,6,6,5,9,10,4,12,9,7,4,4,8,6,9,7,10,6,5,11,11,7,15,8,5,6,8,6,11,10,4,5,5,4,7,11,5,4,4,6,9,12,11,16,15,8,6,5,10,10,6,4,5,4,13,5,13,21,5,5,5,6,5,4,12,5,4,5,8,11,11,5,4,11,4,9,18,16,5,4,5,8,4,12,9,4,5,4,6,5,4,5,11,6,6,9,12,12,10,7,4,4,5,5,19,5,10,6,6,4,5,6,5,12,6,4,5,13,13,7,8,4,4,6,13,7,6,8,14,22,8,6,6,5,10,15,5,5,14,7,7,6,5,6,7,10,6,4,7,10,6,13,5,11,6,7,4,5,11,6,5,6,4,5,5,6,5,20,14,7,11,4,6,9,4,12,7,6,7,6,4,5,7,5,7,11,6,5,4,10,4,11,18,15,4,4,5,7,6,8,8,5,11,10,19,12,9,4,4,4,5,6,4,5,5,5,4,6,5,7,4,5,6,5,4,4,11,7,4,4,5,4,5,10,6,4,6,10,6,9,4,11,6,5,13,8,10,9,8,6,8,4,5,19,5,8,15,9,8,5,10,6,18,5,8,15,8,8,19,7,4,6,4,11,9,16,22,4,12,22,5,7,12,7,12,18,10,17,8,6,15,23,7,4,8,8,11,6,8,6,7,5,10,6,5,12,6,10,23,7,4,6,10,20,4,6,12,8,4,11,17,9,11,6,4,6,4,17,10,9,9,8,10,6,5,17,6,4,9,7,22,10,16,4,4,10,9,10,8,6,11,4,5,10,6,15,17,18,21,6,6,22,19,24,14,6,5};
```

Now I produce a logarithmic histogramm:

```
plot = Histogram[data, {1}, Frame -> True, 
  ScalingFunctions -> "Log", 
  FrameLabel -> {{"count", ""}, {"data", "title"}}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> {{0, Automatic}, {0, Automatic}}]
```

[image]

(I want to use `Frame->True`)

**How can I force that the right bars are not out of the frame? The should exactly be at the right edge?**

Second real problem:

I want to export this plot as a PDF file:

```
Export[StringJoin[$HomeDirectory, "\\plot.pdf"], plot, "PDF"];
```

The result is: **the PDF plot has no axes numbering and no labels** and also the bars at the right edge look different.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `PlotRange -> All` fixes the first issue:

```
plot = Histogram[data, {1}, Frame -> True, ScalingFunctions -> "Log", 
  FrameLabel -> {{"count", ""}, {"data", "title"}}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Exporting the `Rasterize`d version of `plot` fixes the second issue:

```
Import[Export["plot.pdf", Rasterize[plot, RasterSize -> 600], "PDF"]]
```

[image]

Comment: Great solution. How can you adjust (for the first question), that the most right bar ends exactly at the right edge of the plot? `Scaled[.3]` should then be substituted by something different.

Comment: @mrz, please see the new version,